# Solution to the pde $u_t-ku_{xx}+\sin(t)u=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the solution to the pde $$u_t-ku_{xx}+\sin(t)u=0$$ $$u(x,0)=\phi(x)$$ $$0 \le t\lt \infty$$ $$ -\infty \lt x \lt +\infty$$

So far I have found the solution to its ODE$$g'+\sin(t)g=0$$ by using the integrating factor method. So, $g(t)=ce^{\cos(t)}$. Now what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the equation by $e^{\cos(t)}$ and notice $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( e^{\cos(t)}u \right) - k \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left( e^{\cos(t)}u \right) = 0. $$ Put $v(x,t) = e^{\cos(t)}u(x,t)$ so that $$v_t - k v_{xx} = 0$$ and $v(x,0) = e^{\cos(0)}u(x,0) = e \phi(x)$.

Now if you can solve the heat equation, you can solve the original equation.

We know that the heat equation above has solution $$v(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}} \int_\mathbb R e^{(x-y)^2/4kt}[e\phi(y)] dy = \frac{e}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}} \int_\mathbb R e^{(x-y)^2/4kt}\phi(y) dy.$$ Thus $$u(x,t) = e^{-\cos(t)}v(x,t) = \frac{e^{1-\cos(t)}}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}} \int_\mathbb R e^{(x-y)^2/4kt}\phi(y) dy.$$

Comment: I don't see how how $v_t-kv_{xx}=0$. I got $v_t-kv_{xx}=-sin(t)e^{cos(t)}u(x,t)$.

Comment: I'm realized that I made a sign error in the above work which is now fixed. It should be $$v(x,t) = e^{-\cos(t)} u(x,t).$$ 

Note that $$v_t = e^{-\cos(t)} u_t + \sin(t) e^{-\cos(t)} u= e^{-\cos(t)}(u_t + \sin(t) u).$$ But according to the original equation, we have $u_t + \sin(t) u = ku_{xx}.$ Thus $v_t = k e^{-\cos(t)}u_{xx}$. However, since $e^{-\cos(t)}$ doesn't depend on $x$, we have $$ e^{-\cos(t)}u_{xx} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left( e^{-\cos(t)} u \right) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(v) = v_{xx}.$$ Thus $v_t = k v_{xx}$.